# Use HTML formatting in email sent from PHP

Tags: php, html

How can I send HTML formatting through a PHP script?  For some reason, it always shows up as `<b>Example</b>` instead of **`Example`**.  I'm sure I have to include HTML headers somewhere, I just don't know what needs to be done.  I'm a complete PHP nubcake.  :)

Here's my PHP script:  (rather long, sorry!)

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

        $name     = $_POST['name'];
        $email    = $_POST['email'];
        $phone   = $_POST['phone'];
        $subject  = $_POST['subject'];
        $comments = $_POST['comments'];
        $verify   = $_POST['verify'];

        if(trim($name) == '') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">You must enter your name.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(trim($name) == 'Name') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">You must enter your name.</div>';
            exit();
        }

        else if(trim($email) == '') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(trim($email) == 'Email') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Invalid e-mail address, please try again.</div>';
            exit();
        }

        if(trim($subject) == '') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a subject.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(trim($subject) == 'Subject') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a subject.</div>';
            exit();
        }


        if($error == '') {

            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $comments = stripslashes($comments);
            }

         $address = "mynamehere@mydomainnamehere.com";

         $e_subject = '' . $subject . '.';

         $e_body = "<b>Name:</b> $name \n\n<b>Subject:</b> $subject \n\n<b>Email:</b> $email \n\n<b>Message:</b> $comments";
         $e_content = "";
         $e_reply = "";

         $msg = $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply;

         if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n")) {

         echo "<div id='success_page'>";
         echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
         echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been sent!</p>";
         echo "</div>";
         //echo "</fieldset>";

         } else {

         echo 'ERROR!';

         }

    }

function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.

return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));

}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include html in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916477/include-html-in-email)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a content-type to your $additional_headers parameter:

```
$headers  = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {
```

My recommendation would be to do as another poster says and use an external sending service or something like [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) which makes it easy to specify HTML and Plain Text versions (some of us really *hate* HTML email ;))

Comment: might want to use UTF-8 charset as well, but that should do the trick.

Comment: Looks just like what I was wanting.  Thank you!

Comment: Spam filters hate HTML-only mail too. Don't use this code example. Use a decent library to do the job.

Comment: +1 @David Dorward, I also advise you to use this as an example and not a working solution, please do your research first and take the advice of using a library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872639/good-php-email-library

Comment: Hell, it was my answer, and I recommend not using it. Hence, the link to Zend_Mail.

Answer (score 5):

This may not be related to your real issue but your regex is HUGE and Pointless :/

> preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]]).)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]).){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email)

^^ That's madness :/

try something a little more simpler:

```
return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Comment: @RobertPitt: That is a marked improvement, and it would be a nice function...if it was actually correct, in 2011. Unfortunately, it is broken: `bob@example.香港 ` is a perfectly valid e-mail address, as is `Медведев@президент.рф` - alas, Everyone Speaks English Syndrome strikes again, and the function throws these out as invalid.

Comment: And what about his Regex, would that allow such domains, Also if you have the ultimate email *validation* regex that's prefect then please share :)

Comment: Regular expressions are not suited to validating email addresses. Check that there is exactly one `@`, check that the DNS for the part after the `@` resolves, then try to send email to it.

Comment: @RobertPitt: Actually, I just found out about this problem, so I'm mentioning it. So far, it looks that there is an acceptable workaround: convert to punycode, *then* run through the filter. Punycode-encoded IDN e-mail addresses seem to pass the filter correctly.

Comment: @David Dorward: I've checked the regex in @RobertPitt's suggestion, and it is *that* two-page regular expression, which correctly matches valid e-mails, and not invalid e-mails. With Punycode, this fortunately also works for IDNs, so although it is one beast of a regex, it is *correct* (see line 525 here: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?view=markup#l501 ).

Answer (score 3):

You need an HTML header. Add this:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n";
```

Then in your send mail line rewrite it like this:

```
if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers))
```

Also, if I were you I would make it more cross-platform compatible. Newlines in *nix systems is "\n" and in Mac's its "\r". I've never actually worked on a Mac server so I use this to set a New Line define:

```
if(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')
    define('EOL', "\r\n");
else
    define('EOL', "\n");
```

And in my headers I use EOL instead of ."\r\n" so it looks like this:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . EOL
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . EOL;
$headers .= "From: $email".EOL."Reply-To: $email".EOL."Return-Path: $email".EOL.EOL;
```

Also, end your headers with TWO newlines to prevent header injection attacks.

Comment: Interesting note on the TWO newlines. Great post.

Comment: Don't send plain HTML emails! They are unfriendly and recognised by many filters as being spammy. If you must have formatting, use multi-part MIME.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to get all of the details of sending emails correctly (getting past spam filters etc) you can use a library such as http://swiftmailer.org/. It handles setting all of the appropriate headers etc for you.

I have no relation to swiftmailer. I've just used it and liked it.

Comment: Are you a swiftmailer rep? his question was how to do it in PHP not how to get someone else to do it for you. It's pretty simple to set the headers correctly without outsourcing to other classes and libraries

Comment: Sending HTML formatted email well is hard (since you have to do multipart MIME). Reinventing the wheel is bad. The GNU Lesser General Public License is friendly.

Comment: @Daniel - No I'm not, just someone who has used it and liked it. I'll update my answer to make that clearer and will do so in future. As for why, when you are having trouble trying to do something manually, why struggle when you can use a library to assist you. It gets even easier if you are going to be sending a few different types of emails. May as well outsource it to a well tested library rather than trying to get it right yourself (and potentially getting it wrong but not realising).

Comment: Amen. PHP raw `mail()` is extremely low-level for the usual tasks; abstracting that away saves you time (both for writing and debugging) and nerves.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some html headers, sure, at least

```
<html>
  <body>
     Your data
  </body>
</html>
```

and set a correct mime type