# avoid getting HTML tags in email

Tags: php, html, email, tags

I wrote a PHP script for sending email. I am using a CMS which is based on PHP MySQL. I am able to send emails, and people can receive the eamils as well, but the problem is they get HTML tags in their email.

As I am writing the mail by using that CMS and for which i have to write some HTML tags there like `</br>`, `<p>` etc. The code for sending mail is below. What should I change so that people can get nice email without HTML tags, but formatted HTML mail. Thanks for helping me out.

`$sentemail = mail($email_user, $subject, $message,"From: ABC<xyz@.com>\nX-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion());`

Comment: You need to add headers to your email, the [PHP manual mail page](http://php.net/mail) can show you how. See example #4

Comment: Possible [duplicate of this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916477/include-html-in-email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the header to send html email, like that: `$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";`, and then use the header in mail() function instead the From.. statement. Check documentation for more info http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php (example #4)

Comment: `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; ` you've gotta add this line as well buddy.